# How to solve git commit error - ERROR - : type must be one of [build, core, ci,docs, feat, fix, perf, revert, style, test ]

Tags: git, bitbucket

When issuing git commit command, I'm getting below error.

```
$ git commit -am "test commit"
Input: header=test commit body= footer=
ERROR - : type must be one of [build, core, ci,docs, feat, fix, perf, revert, style, test ]
```

I get this every now and then. When I delete the project and clone again, it goes away but comes back again after couple of commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message does not come from git, you must have a custom `pre-commit` hook installed.

Such scripts are generally used to enforce some rules, either on the content that is committed (say : all files should be formatted) or on the branch name or commit message (say : every branch or every commit must reference an issue number).

Check the README, or ask the repo's maintainers what rules apply.

Answer (score 3):

Your commit message must start with:

```
build: ...
```

or

```
core: ...
```

or

```
feat: ...
```

or one of the other types mentioned in the error message.

Comment: Thanks, that answer helped me with this error :D I used "feature" instead of "feat"